# java.lang.IllegalStateException : Cannot get a connection as the driver manager is not properly initialized

Tags: jpa, jdbc, wildfly

I need to use hibernate in my web project. To use it, I made next steps:

1. Added dependencies in build.gradle:

```
implementation('org.hibernate:hibernate-core:6.0.2.Final')
compileOnly(group: 'javax.persistence', name: 'persistence-api', version: '1.0')
```

2. Configured my db in `compose.yaml`:

```
services:
    db:
      image: 'postgres:latest'
      environment:
        - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
        - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
        - POSTGRES_DB=default_database
      ports:
        - 5432:5432
```

3. Located `persistence.xml` in `src/main/resources/META-INF`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
                                 http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd"
             version="1.0">

    <persistence-unit name="Data" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <class>entities.Result</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver" /> <!-- DB Driver -->
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres" /> <!-- BD Mane -->
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="postgres" /> <!-- DB User -->
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="postgres" /> <!-- DB Password -->

            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect"/> <!-- DB Dialect -->
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" /> <!-- create / create-drop / update -->

        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

4. Created a ResultDAO java class, which implements database managment:

```
package utils;
import entities.Result;
import jakarta.persistence.EntityManager;
import jakarta.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import jakarta.persistence.Persistence;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ResultDAO implements DAO<Result> {
    EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("Data");
    EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();

    @Override
    public ArrayList<Result> getAll() {
        try {
            entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
            List results = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT ")
                    .setMaxResults(50)
                    .getResultList();
            entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
            return (ArrayList<Result>) results;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return new ArrayList<Result>();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean save(Result result) {
        try {
            entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
            entityManager.merge(result);
            entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            entityManager.getTransaction().rollback();
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

It's instance is created inside `ResultsBean.java`:

```
package entities;
import jakarta.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
import jakarta.faces.component.UIComponent;
import jakarta.faces.event.ActionEvent;
import jakarta.inject.Named;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.*;
import utils.ResultDAO;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;

@Named
@SessionScoped
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class ResultsBean implements Serializable {
    Result result = new Result();

    ResultDAO resultDAO = new ResultDAO();

    //Загрузка коллекции из БД
    private ArrayList<Result> results = resultDAO.getAll();

    //Добавляет точку в коллекцию из формы.
    public void addPoint() throws IOException {
        Result curRes = new Result();
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss dd.MM.yyyy");
    }
}
```

The unit, which is stored in db is Result:

```
package entities;
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.*;
import java.io.Serializable;
@Entity // Данный бин (класс) является сущностью
@Setter
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
public class Result implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true, name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(nullable = false, name = "x")
    private Integer x;

    @Column(nullable = false, name = "y")
    private Integer y;

    @Column(nullable = false, name = "r")
    private Double r;

    @Column(nullable = false, name = "result")
    private Boolean result;

    @Column(nullable = false, name = "time")
    private String time;
}
```

When I execute `sudo docker compose up` and try to refresh my page, which should be connected to db, I got `Internal Server Error` and a huge wall of errors:

```
web_3      | 13:29:42,377 INFO  [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper] (default task-1) HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: Data]
web_3      | 
web_3      | 13:29:42,381 WARN  [org.hibernate.orm.deprecation] (default task-1) HHH90000021: Encountered deprecated setting [javax.persistence.jdbc.user], use [jakarta.persistence.jdbc.user] instead
web_3      | 13:29:42,381 WARN  [org.hibernate.orm.deprecation] (default task-1) HHH90000021: Encountered deprecated setting [javax.persistence.jdbc.password], use [jakarta.persistence.jdbc.password] instead
web_3      | 
web_3      | 13:29:42,381 WARN  [org.hibernate.orm.deprecation] (default task-1) HHH90000021: Encountered deprecated setting [javax.persistence.jdbc.url], use [jakarta.persistence.jdbc.url] instead
web_3      | 
web_3      | 13:29:42,381 WARN  [org.hibernate.orm.deprecation] (default task-1) HHH90000021: Encountered deprecated setting [javax.persistence.jdbc.driver], use [jakarta.persistence.jdbc.driver] instead
web_3      | 
web_3      | 13:29:42,385 INFO  [org.hibernate.envers.boot.internal.EnversServiceImpl] (default task-1) Envers integration enabled? : true
web_3      | 
web_3      | 13:29:42,390 WARN  [org.hibernate.orm.connections.pooling] (default task-1) HHH10001002: Using built-in connection pool (not intended for production use)
web_3      | 
web_3      | 13:29:42,391 INFO  [org.hibernate.orm.connections.pooling] (default task-1) HHH10001005: Loaded JDBC driver class: org.postgresql.Driver
web_3      | 
web_3      | 13:29:42,391 INFO  [org.hibernate.orm.connections.pooling] (default task-1) HHH10001012: Connecting with JDBC URL [jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres]
web_3      | 
web_3      | 13:29:42,391 INFO  [org.hibernate.orm.connections.pooling] (default task-1) HHH10001001: Connection properties: {password=****, user=postgres}
web_3      | 
web_3      | 13:29:42,391 INFO  [org.hibernate.orm.connections.pooling] (default task-1) HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
web_3      | 
web_3      | 13:29:42,393 INFO  [org.hibernate.orm.connections.pooling] (default task-1) HHH10001115: Connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
web_3      | 
web_3      | 13:29:42,413 WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator] (default task-1) HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot get a connection as the driver manager is not properly initialized
web_3      |    at org.hibernate@6.2.6.Final//org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:262)
web_3      |    at org.hibernate@6.2.6.Final//org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:316)
web_3      |    at org.hibernate@6.2.6.Final//org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:152)
web_3      |    at org.hibernate@6.2.6.Final//org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:34)
web_3      |    at org.hibernate@6.2.6.Final//org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:119)
web_3      |    at org.hibernate@6.2.6.Final//org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:264)
web_3      |    at org.hibernate@6.2.6.Final//org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:239)
web_3      |    at org.hibernate@6.2.6.Final//org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:216)
web_3      |    at org.hibernate@6.2.6.Final//org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:45)
web_3      |    at org.hibernate@6.2.6.Final//org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:125)
web_3      |    at org.hibernate@6.2.6.Final//org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:248)
web_3      |    at org.hibernate@6.2.6.Final//org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:216)
web_3      |    at org.hibernate@6.2.6.Final//org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.convertSqlException(BasicConnectionCreator.java:121)
web_3      |    at org.hibernate@6.2.6.Final//org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverConnectionCreator.java:43)
web_3      |    at org.hibernate@6.2.6.Final//org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.createConnection(BasicConnectionCreator.java:61)
web_3      |    at org.hibernate@6.2.6.Final//org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections.addConnections(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:501)
web_3      |    at org.hibernate@6.2.6.Final//org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections.<init>(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:367)
web_3      |    at org.hibernate@6.2.6.Final//org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections$Builder.build(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:552)
web_3      |    at org.hibernate@6.2.6.Final//org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.buildPool(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:105)
web_3      |    at org.hibernate@6.2.6.Final//org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:81)
web_3      |    at org.hibernate@6.2.6.Final//org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:125)
web_3      |    at org.hibernate@6.2.6.Final//org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:248)
web_3      |    at org.hibernate@6.2.6.Final//org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:216)
web_3      |    at org.hibernate@6.2.6.Final//org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:283)
web_3      |    at org.hibernate@6.2.6.Final//org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:150)
web_3      |    at org.hibernate@6.2.6.Final//org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:34)
web_3      |    at org.hibernate@6.2.6.Final//org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:119)
web_3      |    at org.hibernate@6.2.6.Final//org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:264)
web_3      |    at org.hibernate@6.2.6.Final//org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:239)
web_3      |    at org.hibernate@6.2.6.Final//org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:216)
web_3      |    at org.hibernate@6.2.6.Final//org.hibernate.boot.model.relational.Database.<init>(Database.java:45)
web_3      |    at org.hibernate@6.2.6.Final//org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.getDatabase(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:230)
web_3      |    at org.hibernate@6.2.6.Final//org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:198)
web_3      |    at org.hibernate@6.2.6.Final//org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:166)
web_3      |    at org.hibernate@6.2.6.Final//org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1380)
web_3      |    at org.hibernate@6.2.6.Final//org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1451)
web_3      |    at org.hibernate@6.2.6.Final//org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:55)
web_3      |    at jakarta.persistence.api@3.1.0//jakarta.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:80)
web_3      |    at jakarta.persistence.api@3.1.0//jakarta.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:55)
web_3      |    at deployment.web_3.war//utils.ResultDAO.<init>(ResultDAO.java:10)
web_3      |    at deployment.web_3.war//entities.ResultsBean.<init>(ResultsBean.java:27)
web_3      |    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
web_3      |    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
web_3      |    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
web_3      |    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
web_3      |    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
web_3      |    at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.1.SP1//org.jboss.weld.injection.ConstructorInjectionPoint.newInstance(ConstructorInjectionPoint.java:119)
web_3      |    at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.1.SP1//org.jboss.weld.injection.ConstructorInjectionPoint.invokeAroundConstructCallbacks(ConstructorInjectionPoint.java:92)
web_3      |    at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.1.SP1//org.jboss.weld.injection.ConstructorInjectionPoint.newInstance(ConstructorInjectionPoint.java:78)
web_3      |    at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.1.SP1//org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.AbstractInstantiator.newInstance(AbstractInstantiator.java:28)
web_3      |    at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.1.SP1//org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.BasicInjectionTarget.produce(BasicInjectionTarget.java:112)
web_3      |    at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.1.SP1//org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.BeanInjectionTarget.produce(BeanInjectionTarget.java:186)
web_3      |    at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.1.SP1//org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean.create(ManagedBean.java:160)
web_3      |    at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.1.SP1//org.jboss.weld.util.bean.IsolatedForwardingBean.create(IsolatedForwardingBean.java:45)
web_3      |    at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.1.SP1//org.jboss.weld.contexts.AbstractContext.get(AbstractContext.java:96)
web_3      |    at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.1.SP1//org.jboss.weld.contexts.PassivatingContextWrapper$AbstractPassivatingContextWrapper.get(PassivatingContextWrapper.java:84)
web_3      |    at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.1.SP1//org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstanceStrategy$DefaultContextualInstanceStrategy.get(ContextualInstanceStrategy.java:100)
web_3      |    at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.1.SP1//org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstanceStrategy$CachingContextualInstanceStrategy.get(ContextualInstanceStrategy.java:177)
web_3      |    at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.1.SP1//org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstance.get(ContextualInstance.java:50)
web_3      |    at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.1.SP1//org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:680)
web_3      |    at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.1.SP1//org.jboss.weld.module.web.el.AbstractWeldELResolver.lookup(AbstractWeldELResolver.java:107)
web_3      |    at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.1.SP1//org.jboss.weld.module.web.el.AbstractWeldELResolver.getValue(AbstractWeldELResolver.java:90)
web_3      |    at jakarta.faces.impl@4.0.2//com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:139)
web_3      |    at jakarta.faces.impl@4.0.2//com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:164)
web_3      |    at org.glassfish.expressly@5.0.0//org.glassfish.expressly.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:97)
web_3      |    at org.glassfish.expressly@5.0.0//org.glassfish.expressly.parser.AstValue.getBase(AstValue.java:314)
web_3      |    at org.glassfish.expressly@5.0.0//org.glassfish.expressly.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:140)
web_3      |    at org.glassfish.expressly@5.0.0//org.glassfish.expressly.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:138)
web_3      |    at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.1.SP1//org.jboss.weld.module.web.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:50)
web_3      |    at jakarta.faces.impl@4.0.2//com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:73)
web_3      |    at jakarta.faces.impl@4.0.2//jakarta.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:206)
web_3      |    at jakarta.faces.impl@4.0.2//jakarta.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:175)
web_3      |    at jakarta.faces.impl@4.0.2//jakarta.faces.component.UIOutput.getValue(UIOutput.java:134)
web_3      |    at jakarta.faces.impl@4.0.2//jakarta.faces.component.UIInput.getValue(UIInput.java:287)
web_3      |    at jakarta.faces.impl@4.0.2//com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicInputRenderer.getValue(HtmlBasicInputRenderer.java:163)
web_3      |    at jakarta.faces.impl@4.0.2//com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.getCurrentValue(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:303)
web_3      |    at jakarta.faces.impl@4.0.2//com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeEnd(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:135)
web_3      |    at jakarta.faces.impl@4.0.2//jakarta.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:585)
web_3      |    at jakarta.faces.impl@4.0.2//jakarta.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1442)
web_3      |    at jakarta.faces.impl@4.0.2//jakarta.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:146)
web_3      |    at jakarta.faces.impl@4.0.2//jakarta.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:556)
web_3      |    at jakarta.faces.impl@4.0.2//jakarta.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1435)
web_3      |    at jakarta.faces.impl@4.0.2//jakarta.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1438)
web_3      |    at jakarta.faces.impl@4.0.2//jakarta.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1438)
web_3      |    at jakarta.faces.impl@4.0.2//com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:441)
web_3      |    at jakarta.faces.impl@4.0.2//com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:163)
web_3      |    at jakarta.faces.impl@4.0.2//jakarta.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:125)
web_3      |    at jakarta.faces.impl@4.0.2//com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:93)
web_3      |    at jakarta.faces.impl@4.0.2//com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:72)
web_3      |    at jakarta.faces.impl@4.0.2//com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:178)
web_3      |    at jakarta.faces.impl@4.0.2//jakarta.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.executeLifecyle(FacesServlet.java:692)
web_3      |    at jakarta.faces.impl@4.0.2//jakarta.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:449)
web_3      |    at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.7.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)
web_3      |    at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.7.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
web_3      |    at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.7.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68)
web_3      |    at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.7.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
web_3      |    at org.wildfly.security.elytron-web.undertow-server@4.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.elytron.web.undertow.server.ElytronRunAsHandler.lambda$handleRequest$1(ElytronRunAsHandler.java:68)
web_3      |    at org.wildfly.security.elytron-base@2.2.1.Final//org.wildfly.security.auth.server.FlexibleIdentityAssociation.runAsFunctionEx(FlexibleIdentityAssociation.java:103)
web_3      |    at org.wildfly.security.elytron-base@2.2.1.Final//org.wildfly.security.auth.server.Scoped.runAsFunctionEx(Scoped.java:161)
web_3      |    at org.wildfly.security.elytron-base@2.2.1.Final//org.wildfly.security.auth.server.Scoped.runAs(Scoped.java:73)
web_3      |    at org.wildfly.security.elytron-web.undertow-server@4.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.elytron.web.undertow.server.ElytronRunAsHandler.handleRequest(ElytronRunAsHandler.java:67)
web_3      |    at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.7.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.RedirectDirHandler.handleRequest(RedirectDirHandler.java:68)
web_3      |    at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.7.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:117)
web_3      |    at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.7.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
web_3      |    at io.undertow.core@2.3.7.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
web_3      |    at io.undertow.core@2.3.7.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
web_3      |    at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.7.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
web_3      |    at io.undertow.core@2.3.7.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
web_3      |    at org.wildfly.security.elytron-web.undertow-server-servlet@4.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.elytron.web.undertow.server.servlet.CleanUpHandler.handleRequest(CleanUpHandler.java:38)
web_3      |    at io.undertow.core@2.3.7.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
web_3      |    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@29.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
web_3      |    at io.undertow.core@2.3.7.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
web_3      |    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@29.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:68)
web_3      |    at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.7.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.SendErrorPageHandler.handleRequest(SendErrorPageHandler.java:52)
web_3      |    at io.undertow.core@2.3.7.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
web_3      |    at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.7.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:276)
web_3      |    at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.7.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
web_3      |    at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.7.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:132)
web_3      |    at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.7.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
web_3      |    at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.7.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
web_3      |    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@29.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1430)
web_3      |    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@29.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1430)
web_3      |    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@29.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1430)
web_3      |    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@29.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1430)
web_3      |    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@29.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1430)
web_3      |    at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.7.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:256)
web_3      |    at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.7.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:101)
web_3      |    at io.undertow.core@2.3.7.Final//io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:393)
web_3      |    at io.undertow.core@2.3.7.Final//io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:859)
web_3      |    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
web_3      |    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
web_3      |    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
web_3      |    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1348)
web_3      |    at org.jboss.xnio@3.8.9.Final//org.xnio.XnioWorker$WorkerThreadFactory$1$1.run(XnioWorker.java:1282)
web_3      |    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

All in all, the problem occurs in string `EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();` of ResultDAO. Seems it can't create a new instance of EntityManager. The project is available on [github](https://github.com/vovibssnff/web_3.git)
If you got any additional questions, just ask. I have no idea what am I doing wrong with my jpa...

Comment: @BalusC , can you please provide some guides how shall I use hibernates, built-in in wildfly? And do you mean search engine of project or just google?